# Non cancellable notification React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

I am working on feature where the user is reminded for a medication at a certain time and day.

The user can not ignore the notification which means he has to either take the medication and snooze the reminder. It has to be a noncancellable notification that user cant swipe to ignore (I hope this is making sense).

I've implemented [React Native Push Notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) and it works fine as far as getting notification/reminder about medication is concerned but my problem is user can always swipe the notification to ignore it which I don't want.

Is there any way to get a noncancellable notification which requires user to respond to the notification?

Thanks.